# Not able to execute custom function extension in wso2 cep

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I am using **wso2cep 4.1.0** and have created custom function extension class with following package name:

```
package org.wso2.siddhi.extension.custom;

.....

public class MyFunction extends FunctionExecutor {
.....
}
```

Then I have created file : **custom.siddhiext**

An put following entry into it.

```
mycount=org.wso2.siddhi.extension.custom.MyFunction
```

I have created jar including both of above files.
I have created maven project for above.

**Then i put this jar to /repository/components/dropins folder.**

And restarted cep wso2server.

Now i am executing following execution plan:
**My execution plan:**

```
from inputstream#window.timeBatch( 1 sec )

select custom:mycount(param1) as outparam
insert into outputstream;
```

**On creating outputsteam i get following exception:**

**Exception when validating the stream, exception : 'mycount' is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension in execution plan "ExecutionPlan"**

It seems like jar i put in dropin folder is not read by wso2server but i followed steps stated in [https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Writing+a+Custom+Function+Extension]

anybody have face similar issues or have solution for it.

During restart of wso2cepserver i get following ERROR:

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer} -  Required Bundle manifest headers do not exists: /home/analytics/wso2cep-4.1                                                                     .0/repository/components/dropins/function-extension-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using the [maven-bundle-plugin](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/develop-osgi-bundles-using-maven-bundle-plugin) to build the bundle. If so, in your extension project pom file, recheck maven-bundle-plugin configurations.

Check whether the `Bundle-SymbolicName` has being provided to the plugin. You may refer to [this example of another extension, being written to Siddhi](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-window-unique-time/blob/master/pom.xml#L64).

[According to the source code](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.3/core/org.wso2.carbon.server/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/server/extensions/DropinsBundleDeployer.java#L107) (the source of Carbon 4.4.3 DropinsBundleDeployer which deploys the bundles we put into the dropins folder), this error could occur:

1. when the `Bundle-SymbolicName` has not being given or
2. when the `Bundle-Version` has not being given.

So in case, putting the `Bundle-SymbolicName` in to the config didn't make a difference, I would try adding the `Bundle-Version` as well. You can find a sample config in this [maven-bundle-plugin tutorial](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/develop-osgi-bundles-using-maven-bundle-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other extension which has the same `org.wso2.siddhi.extension.custom` package name? If so try renaming the package to something else.